KOrganizer won't work because of Akonadi
When I start KOrganizer it won't start and give me the following output in terminal:
Connecting to deprecated signal QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Starting up the Akonadi Server...
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: database server stopped unexpectedly
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/reneas/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/reneas/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.socket", "--pid-file=/run/user/1000/akonadi/mysql.pid")
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stdout: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: stderr: ""
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: exit code: 1
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: process error: "Unknown error"
org.kde.pim.akonadiserver: Shutting down AkonadiServer...
org.kde.pim.akonadicontrol: Application '/usr/bin/akonadiserver' exited normally...
org.kde.pim.korganizer: Search failed:  ""
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Failed to fetch tags:  ""
org.kde.pim.akonadicore: Job error:  "" for collection: QVector()

I don't really understand why it is not working but after some research I checked /run/user/1000/akonadi and saw that the folder is empty.
What can I do to resolve this? I'm using KOrganizer to import my Nextcloud Calendars into the system calendar.
Before I upgraded to Kubuntu 24.04 from 22.04 everything worked fine.
